# where vs sort: Which is more efficient?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

Which is more efficient - where or sort?
I have a huge size of data and efficiency matters to me. Should I do 'where' first, or 'sort' first?

> |where count>100
> |sort count fruits

OR

> |sort count fruits
> |where count>100

Answer (score 2):

Filtering first (with `where` or other commands) is more efficient.  It means the downstream commands have less to process so they work faster and use fewer resources.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" answer is the one @RichG [gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486596/4418)

However, as with most things in life, the "reality" answer is "it depends"

It *should* be the case that filtering before sorting will be more efficient

But I have seen instances where filtering *later* is actually more efficient (depends on a host of factors) - so you really need to try it both ways to be sure

Docs.Splunk links:

- [where](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/where)
- [sort](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/sort)